# Is it possible to understand which people meet in outlook calendar, without sharing the calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I share calendar with some colleagues, and I can see who they meet. But for others I wouldn't ask to share because they are not in my "circle".

However, if I guess who is probably participating in a meeting, just comparing manually the respective calendars I can understand the dynamic among people.

Isn't it possible to do it automatically? After all the information is public, it would be just a matter of finding people with the same meeting at the same time.

I wonder if this kind of automation exists, either with API, outlook plugin or power automation.

Comment: `After all the information is public` ... no it is not ... it belongs to your employer

Comment: _understand the dynamic among people_  - looks like someone has issues with micromanagment... Why does the dynamic even matter? Aren't they delivering the results? What about their Teams' calls? There's also dynamics here. One doesn't need a meeting for everything. But you could use Microsoft Graph to programatically access all the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't it possible to do it automatically? After all the information is public, it would be just a matter of finding people with the same meeting at the same time.
>
> I wonder if this kind of automation exists, either with API, outlook plugin or power automation.

To the best of my knowledge, no, it's not possible.

Actually, meeting details like subject is not visible to others unless the calendar owner modifies the default permission which only shows the free/busy status. So, without sufficient permissions to see the meeting subject on others' calendars, it's even not feasible to do it manually because you cannot tell whether or not they are occupied by the same meeting although they are "busy" in the same time slot.

And even if you do have the permission to see meeting details, I am not aware of any automatic way which can do this trick.